# Chrome: Deleting All History Entries of a Specific Website

Tags: google-chrome, history

I'm using Chrome on Mac and Windows, and I would like to delete all history entries of a specific website. Those amount to dozens of history pages, so even when using mouse clicks while pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to clear an entire page, having to sift through dozens of pages will be very tiresome.

And I would like to avoid deleting all of the browsing history.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/fieldguide.gizmodo.com/how-to-delete-just-one-site-from-your-chrome-browsing-h-1738639969/amp

Comment: Thanks a lot. This eHistory extension is exactly what I was looking for. I'm not sure why I can't flag your comment as the answer, but as I see this question as answered. Thanks.